# What is a word that also means "cascadingly"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I read this online,

> When the TTL controller cleans up the Job, it will delete the Job **cascadingly**

but the word ***cascadingly*** does not strike me as a word and I believe this could be rephrased, but I am not sure how. I looked around and there is usage of this word, but not in a dictionary that I could find and maybe it's because it's in use in another non-US English and makes sense there like "touristic." Although I have this tagged as a single-word request, it doesn't necessarily have to be. I believe a rephrasing is in order.

Comment: If it were multiple jobs, I could understand that there is a cascade.  Let's suppose there really is a cascade.  Then *it will delete the jobs in a cascade.*

Comment: It's better to be more specific about what will be deleted: "it will delete any other jobs the selected job has created", or "it will delete any other jobs the job has communicated with" or "woken" or whatever it actually does. Nobody wants a job deleted unexpectedly.

Comment: "When the TTL controller cleans up the job, it will delete the job **in turn**," MW - "in turn": in due order of succession. (PS "Job" is not capitalised here.)

Comment: I agree with @Greybeard - But I might go one step further and (If this is what it’s trying to say) go with: “When the TTL controller cleans up the job, it will delete the job and all of its children in turn.”

Comment: What is the intent? If it is 'one after another', it's doing it _iteratively_. If one job is composed of other jobs, and the deletion cascades through the hierarchy, it's doing it _recursively_.

Comment: Wrong metaphor. Ida said _from top to bottom_.

Comment: Do you mean... recursively?

Answer (score 1):

There's some critical ambiguity in that phrasing with the word "cascadingly".
Does it mean that the TTL controller will...

1. delete things in order of hierarchy such that the lowest items
   are removed first.
2. delete things in the order that they are listed within the data structure, which is a cascading list.
3. provide the user with a cascading list to explore the job data in an organized format so that they may choose what they wish to delete.

If it's trying to describe option 1 I'd write "it will delete the files of the job in order of ascending hierarchy"

If it's trying to describe option 2 I'd use one of the following:
"it will delete all parts of the Job in series" or
"it will delete the job and all nested data sequentially"

If it's trying to describe option 3 then it really needs to explain things in greater detail to be clear that it is an interactive process, not a fully automated one.

Answer (score 0):

This term stems from the word "cascade" as deriving its sense originally in the technologies of electronics.

It is found in electronics in connection with amplifiers and digital cicuits; when you say that amplifiers are connected in (a) cascade you mean that the output of an amplifier is connected to the output of another, that is, in other words, that the output of an amplifier feeds the input of another. One speaks often of a *cascade of amplifiers*. The idea is similar for logic gates. It communicates roughly the notion of "one after the other".

The same idea is found in chemistry.

> ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cascade#English)) (chemistry) A series of reactions in which the product of one becomes a reactant in the next

The word "cascadingly" has since then been used in various fields with this meaning : *electronics*, *mathematics*, *physics*, *artificial intelligence*, *neuroscience*,  *philosophy of technology*, *sociology*, … ([cascadingly](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cascadingly%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en))

This term has been found in the fields just mentioned and many other connected fields since the beginning of the 21rst century; it  has come to be used even more widely to "overspill" into the humanities and current language.

> ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cascadingly)) **cascadingly** (comparative more cascadingly, superlative most cascadingly)     In a cascade; as if falling one after the other.

Apparently, this is a term that has gained a wide enough currency, indisputably so  in specialized fields and also in the current language, although in this latter domain usage might still be shaky.

If you want to rephrase this you have to understand that the use of "cascadingly" presupposes the existence of elements that are somehow connected, and rephrasing should include mentioning them. If, for instance, the job consists of a number of separate calculations that give rise to accessory manipulations of no further use after the results are obtained, then these calculations have to be mentioned (by whatever name they go by usually).

- When the TTL controller cleans up the Job, it will delete the sets of auxiliary computations one after the other.

There is a term that is very similar to "cascadingly" because  the steps do not have to be recalled; it is the term "sequentially"; however, it does not express the idea of one process triggering the next as markedly as "cascadingly".

- When the TTL controller cleans up the Job, it will delete the Job sequentially.